# Pdfkit - outlinefor(item:) - bug?

Tags: ios11, pdfkit

Anyone else having trouble with this method? In my case it keeps returning the last outline present in the PDF document. Is that a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a known bug of iOS 11.2.
See: http://www.openradar.me/37203575.

Comment: The same. Hope for the better in ios 12